# Kukai and Umami Wallet Error for batch transaction but Successful for Temple wallet

Tags: taquito, beacon, kukai

When I try performing batch transactions, It works with Temple Wallet but when testing on Kukai it says too many transactions and while testing on Umami it says Beacon Error.
Two transactions I am performing are Tez Transfer and Origination.
What can be the issue with any idea?

Code:

```
    await dappClient().CheckIfWalletConnected()
    const tezos = await dappClient().tezos();
    const batch = await tezos.wallet.batch()
         .withTransfer({ to: FEE_RECIPIENT, amount: FEE })
         .withOrigination({
             code: contractCode,
             storage: storage,
        }).send();
    setTxnMessage('Waiting for Confirmation ...');
    await batch.confirmation();
```

Kukai Error
[image: Kukai Error]

Umami Error
[image: Umami Error]

Temple Success Message
[image: Tezos Success Message]

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer on tezos-dev Slack.

> Kukai currently handles origination but not in certain batches, rather
> than a quick fix we refactored payload processing which includes a
> generic payload handler and UI — the work is done but we are focused
> on other high priorities so it won’t likely go live for another two
> weeks. in the meantime, as you pointed out, Temple has a good generic
> handler for such payloads